# c++ Vector сам перезаписывает значения в нём

Tags: c++, vector

Только начинаю пробовать векторы и не понимаю почему в нем изменяется значения. Использую Qt 5.8.0.

В ходе for у vector'а сами перезаписываются значения

```
char *strS=new char[5];
std::vector <char*>yrus;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    sprintf (strS, "%d", i+1);//Занести в char strR значения int i+1
    if(yrus.empty()){//Если вектор пустой занести strS
         yrus.insert(yrus.end(),strS);
    }
 }
```

При выполнении`yrus.insert(yrus.end(),strS);` заносит 1 в пустой вектор[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но потом значения yrus[0] меняются вместе с strS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить, чтоб в векторе оставалась "1" в ходе выполнения цикла for?

Comment: Это **вы** лично переписываете значения в `strS`. Почему вы решили, что это вектор их переписывает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При добавлении в вектор (кстати, делайте это не с помощью `insert`, а `push_back`)
у вас добавляется неизменный **указатель** `strS`, так что (все, если будут еще таковые) указатели в векторе одинаковы... А потом вы меняете содержимое в памяти в месте, куда он указывает. Еще раз - *указатель остается тем же - меняется содержимое*.

Вам надо или постоянно создавать новые указатели - типа

```
std::vector <char*>yrus;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    char *strS=new char[5];
    sprintf (strS, "%d", i+1);//Занести в char strR значения int i+1
    yrus.push_back(strS);
 }
```

или, что лучше - работать со строками `string`.

```
std::vector<string> yrus;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    yrus.push_back(to_string(i+1));
}
```

В этих вариантах у вас первым элементом будет С-строка (или строка `string`) `"1"`, которая не будет изменяться. Но при использовании C-строк вы должны потом во избежание утечек памяти *самостоятельно* освободить память для всех элементов вектора. В случае `string` это будет сделано автоматически при выходе вектора из области видимости.

Comment: Да, действительно `string` помог. Но не могу его далее по коду приспособить к делению на лексемы `char* pch = strtok (yrus[0]," ");` `strtok` только с `char` работает? `String` как-то можно применить?

Comment: разделять на лексемы std::string можно разными способами. В  SO уже есть многочисленные ответы по этой теме